# How to check whether the auto brightness option is enabled or not in iPhone using ObjectiveC?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, settings

I want to know whether the auto brightness option in the Brightness Settings is enabled or not and also want to know the default brightness value or the value of the brightness was set by the device owner.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the current brightness with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness]` and set it with `[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:X]` (with X a float between 0.0 - 1.0). It will only affect your app though, and return back to whatever the user had set when she exits your app.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I want to know the brightness value set by the device owner. Say for example, I'm using iPhone5, in my iPhone5 I set auto-brightness "ON" and the brightness level to 25% on the slider, then when I use [[UIScreen mainScreen] brightness] it would give me a value which would be not as exact as that 25% because the brightness would have been changed because of auto brightness.

Comment: Apple's official public APIs do not allow an iOS app to access General settings in the Settings app. So it is not possible  to change/ detect the toggle button inside the settings app.

Comment: you could search for private API but then your app will be rejected by apple appstore as it is sandboxed. still if you create your app then you could upload it on Cydia (app store for jailbroken apple device)

Comment: @iCanCode: I don't think there is such a method unfortunately. If you think you have a good reason why it should be added, you can try to file a ticket on http://bugreporter.apple.com. Don't expect a quick answer though ;)